# Exporting arbitrary fields in list of dataclass objects to a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-dataclasses

Consider this example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, astuple

@dataclass
class Player:
  id: int
  name: str
  color: str

players = [
  Player(123, "Alice", "green"),
  Player(456, "Bob", "red"),
  Player(789, "Gemma", "blue"),
]

print("players:", players)
print("players[0] as dict:", asdict( players[0] ) )
```

The printout I get is:

```
players: [Player(id=123, name='Alice', color='green'), Player(id=456, name='Bob', color='red'), Player(id=789, name='Gemma', color='bl
ue')]
players[0] as dict: {'id': 123, 'name': 'Alice', 'color': 'green'}
```

Given that all of the entries above have unique values, what would be an easy way to convert specific pairs of `Player` class fields from the `players` into a dict?

For instance, if I want to specify `Player.id` as key and `Player.name` as value, then the corresponding dict based on the `players` list will be:

```
{
  123: 'Alice',
  456: 'Bob',
  789: 'Gemma'
}
```

The inverse, where  `Player.name` is taken as key and `Player.id` as value, would then be:

```
{
  'Alice': 123,
  'Bob':   456,
  'Gemma': 789
}
```

... or if I want `Player.name` as key, and `Player.color` as value, from the `players` list I'd get:

```
{
  'Alice': 'green',
  'Bob':   'red',
  'Gemma': 'blue'
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this (other that loop through the list, and then construct the dictionary "manually")?

Also, in case some values in the list are not unique, how could such a technique be persuaded to only "save" the first key/value combo it encounters in the dict, and ignore subsequent duplicates of the key?

Comment: Why not use dict comprehension ?

Comment: Thanks @zaki98 - its been such along time since I last used dict comprehension, I had forgotten all about it; if anyone can provide an example based on the example above, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry i just assumed you knew and didn't want to use it for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension. To ignore all but the first occurrence of the value for a specific key, you can reverse the `list` first.

```py
k = 'id'
v = 'name'
res = {getattr(p, k): getattr(p, v) for p in reversed(players)}
```

Comment: it also work with dictionary comprehension

Comment: Awesome, many thanks @Unmitigated - works great, and is quite readable for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really like using `getattr` and i prefer using the attributes directly. this Makes it easier for the IDE to detect types and do autocompletion.

```py
d = {
    player.id: player.name for player in players
}
```

or if you want a list

```py
id_list = [player.id for player in players]
```